# Go - mgo, retrieve all nested fields from the collection

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a db structure defined in a following way.

```
{
    name: "Jane",
    films: [
        {
            title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
            year: "1994"
        },
        {
            title: "The Godfather",
            year: "1972"
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Jack",
    films: [
        {
            title: "12 Angry Men",
            year: "1957"
        },
        {
            title: "The Dark Knight",
            year: "2008"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to return a slice of all films - `[]Film` and, if possible, in another query a slice of all titles - `[]string` from the collection. I can pull out entire collection and extract relevant data in the application logic, but is it possible to achieve within a query? I've tried to work with `Select()` method, something like this: `c.Find(nil).Select(<various conditions>).All(&results)` but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is one of the most popular questions on `mongo` tag. And I must say if you need that you are doing something wrong and maybe you should use RDBMS instead of Mongo as performance drop on this kind of queries will nullify all profit from Mongo's features like schemaless, "all-in-one" documents, etc..

Anyway, the answer is simple - you can't get films list as you want. Mongo's `find` can return only complete or partial top-level documents. I mean the best result you can get with the `db.collection.find({}, {'films': 1})` query is the list like

```
{
    films: [
        {
            title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
            year: 1994
        },
        {
            title: "The Godfather",
            year: 1972
        }
    ]
},
{
    films: [
        {
            title: "12 Angry Men",
            year: 1957
        },
        {
            title: "The Dark Knight",
            year: 2008
        }
    ]
}
```

Not what you are expectied, right?

The only way to get array like

```
{
    title: "The Shawshank Redemption",
    year: 1994
},
{
    title: "The Godfather",
    year: 1972
},
{
    title: "12 Angry Men",
    year: 1957
},
{
    title: "The Dark Knight",
    year: 2008
}
```

is to use <kbd>[aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)</kbd>.

The basic Mongo query to retrieve array of films is

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$films'
}, {
    $project: {
        title: '$films.title',
        year: '$films.year'
    }
}])
```

Go's code for this query is

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("db").C("collection")

    pipe := c.Pipe(
        []bson.M{
            bson.M{
                "$unwind": "$films",
            },
            bson.M{
                "$project": bson.M{
                    "title": "$films.title",
                    "year": "$films.year",
                },
            },
        },
    )
    result := []bson.M{}
    err = pipe.All(&result)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", result) // [map[_id:ObjectIdHex("57a2ed6640ce01187e1c9164") title:The Shawshank Redemption year:1994] map[_id:ObjectIdHex("57a2ed6640ce01187e1c9164") title:The Godfather year:1972] map[_id:ObjectIdHex("57a2ed6f40ce01187e1c9165") title:12 Angry Men year:1957] map[year:2008 _id:ObjectIdHex("57a2ed6f40ce01187e1c9165") title:The Dark Knight]]
}
```

If you need additional conditions to select top-level documents code would be

```
pipe := c.Pipe(
    []bson.M{
        bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{
                "name": "Jane",
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$unwind": "$films",
        },
        bson.M{
            "$project": bson.M{
                "title": "$films.title",
                "year": "$films.year",
            },
        },
    },
)
// result [map[_id:ObjectIdHex("57a2ed6640ce01187e1c9164") title:The Shawshank Redemption year:1994] map[title:The Godfather year:1972 _id:ObjectIdHex("57a2ed6640ce01187e1c9164")]]
```

And if you need to filter films you can use next query

```
pipe := c.Pipe(
    []bson.M{
        bson.M{
            "$unwind": "$films",
        },
        bson.M{
            "$project": bson.M{
                "title": "$films.title",
                "year": "$films.year",
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{
                "year": bson.M{
                    "$gt": 2000,
                },
            },
        },
    },
)
// result [map[_id:ObjectIdHex("57a2ed6f40ce01187e1c9165") year:2008 title:The Dark Knight]]
```

The problem with aggregation is the simple fact that most part of aggregation operations doesn't use the indexes and could be slow on large collections. That's why I suggested you to think about RDBMS which can be better choice if you need a lot of aggregations.

And there is no way to get `[]string` from `mgo` as it always returns `bson.M` (or `[]bson.M`) which is `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. Perhaps you're right and I would be better off with Postgres.

Comment: @curious_gudleif smart choice.